# My jquery function I dont think is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu and some buttons below in my HTML:

```
<p>
    <select name="numberDrop" id="numberDropId" onClick="getButtons()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <input class="answerBtns" id="answerA" type="button" value="A" onclick="getButtons(this.id);" /> 
    <input class="answerBtns" id="answerB" type="button" value="B" onclick="getButtons(this.id);"/> 
    <input class="answerBtns" id="answerC" type="button" value="C" onclick="getButtons(this.id);"/> 
    <input class="answerBtns" id="answerD" type="button" value="D" onclick="getButtons(this.id);"/> 
    <input class="answerBtns" id="answerE" type="button" value="E" onclick="getButtons(this.id);"/>
</p>
```

This is what I want to happen: Lets say user selects 3 in the dropdown menu for example, then if the user clicks on a button, it will highlight the button in a color (lets say green) but the user can only have three buttons selected.

If an additional button is clicked then that button would not be selected. The additional button can only be selected if the user unselects a selected button and then selects the button he wishes. This means that only 3 buttons can be selected at maximum.

Less than 3 buttons cannot be selected as well, it has to be 3 buttons if the user has chosen 3 in the dropdown menu.

I have tried using a jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` but I don't know how to retrieve the value from the dropdown list and I cannot tell if a button is selected or not. Can somebody tell me if this jQuery method is correct or not and what do i need to put in my javascript or my css to make selected button green and unselected button back to grey?

Below is my function for if I only want 3 buttons selected:

```
function getButtons(id)
{
    if ($('#' + id).hasClass('answerBtnsSelected'))
        $('#' + id).removeClass('answerBtnsSelected');
    else
    {
        if ($('.answerBtnsSelected').length != 3 )
        {
            $('#' + id).addClass('answerBtnsSelected');
        }
        else
        {
             alert('Only three buttons can be selected.');
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: It's like you are using jquery, but not at the same time.

Comment: This code is terrible. Everytime you make $("#"+id), you make DOM traversal which is costy. Store it in a variable, and be efficient like the cool kids, please.

Comment: take another look at how you are getting `numberDrop`. My guess is that it's `undefined`.

Comment: as Dbugger states, definitely cash nodes in a variable if you need to call the selector more than once...way more efficient.

Comment: I editted my code to what it was previously where I only wanted 3 buttons to be selected else alert but how I can I do this by retrieving the number 3 from the drop down menu.

Comment: i think onchange @ select box would be batter than onclick to develop this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As [Google will tell you](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery+get+value+of+select), you use the [jQuery .val() method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to determine the current value of a select element (or an input or textarea). Then you can use the unary plus operator to take that string and change it into a number. (You may want to update your first option element to have a value of 0, but the following code should cope with it as is.)

So, delete all of your inline onclicks and use jQuery to setup the handlers, add in what I just told you about `.val()`, and you get something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".answerBtns").click(function() {
        var btn = $(this),
            selectionLimit = +$("numberDropId").val() || 0;

        if (btn.hasClass('answerBtnsSelected'))
            btn.removeClass('answerBtnsSelected');
        else if ($('.answerBtnsSelected').length < selectionLimit)
            btn.addClass('answerBtnsSelected');
        else
            alert('Only ' + selectionLimit + ' buttons can be selected.');
    });
});
```

I haven't actually tested the above, but it should get you well past the bit you're currently stuck on.

Regarding the following point in your question:

> Less than 3 buttons cannot be selected as well, it has to be 3 buttons if the user has chosen 3 in the dropdown menu

I have no idea how you expect that to work. If the user wants to change their selection they'll have to deselect one or more of the currently selected buttons.

Comment: if you remove the onclicks, make sure to place your jQuery code in `document.ready(function{...});` and remove the `function`

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention document ready explictly in my answer. The code I showed above uses the shortcut version of the document ready syntax and is intended to completely replace the existing `getButtons()` function.

Comment: Thanks for that @punit. Here's an updated fiddle with a simple class added to the CSS so that the buttons change colour when selected: http://jsfiddle.net/P8p3g/2/